# how to check if a c# list contains only the given value ??

Tags: .net, list, c#-4.0

I want to check a list for a given value and the list should contain only the given value. Say for example

```
List<string> alltypes = new List<string>();
```

i want to check 'alltypes' for something like a value 'sedan' and if that is the only element in the list alltypes then return true

Appreciate any help..thank u

Answer (score 2):

use Linq All query - will return true if all members of the list match the input query

```
var result = alltypes.Count > 0 && alltypes.All(a => a == "sedan")
```

result will be true if list only contains strings of "sedan"

Answer (score 2):

Depends if you are saying there should be one and only one value

```
var result = alltypes.Length == 1 && alltypes[0] == "sedan"
```

or if you are saying all the values in the the list (and there may be many)

```
var result = alltypes.Length > 0  && alltypes.All(a => a == "sedan")
```

Careful with [All](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548541%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) as it will return true if the list is empty:

> true if every element of the source sequence passes the test in the
>   specified predicate, or if the sequence is empty; otherwise, false.